# Make Foreign key unique that is referencing to a unique primary key?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relationship, primary-key

I am creating a database in mysql and my question is if i should make a foreign key that is referencing to an already unique Primary key also unique?

Comment: *if i should make a foreign key that is referencing to an already unique Primary key also unique?* No.

Comment: It depends, do you want the relationship to be 1:N or 1:1? If the latter, then yes, make it unique.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Here are the two possible scenarios:

**1:N** Table `homes` has a foreign key `owner_id` to table `owners`, stating which owner owns a home. Since an owner can own more than one home, some homes might have the same `owner_id`, so it shouldn't be unique.

**1:1** Table `tax_records` has a foreign key `owner_id` to table `owners`, stating who is the owner of the tax record. Since an owner can have only one tax record, the `owner_id` should show up only once in the `tax_records` table, and therefore should be unique. **Have in mind** that 1:1 relationships can be implemented in 2 ways, you could also have a foreign key `tax_record_id` in the `owners` table. The right choice is to put the foreign key to the entity that "belongs" to the other entity. E.g. a tax record belongs to an owner, so you should have a foreign key `owner_id` in the `tax_records` table.